# I am working on a custom Listview for android that holds togglebutton (working on an alarm application)

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-adapter, android-togglebutton

The problem I am having is that the `OnCheckedChangeListener` is being called if I scroll, and randomly switching the toggle state for other items in the list. I have worked a way around this for now(loading the state for the toggle button from a database field) but I do want an explanation as to why the `OnCheckedChangeListener` for the togglebutton is active while scrolling, so I don't run into problems later.
Right now this is all I am doing with the code to test it.

```
btnToggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                boolean isChecked) {

            Log.d("", "" + model.getId());

        }   
    });
```

Comment: Can you provide code how the click is being interpreted in the listener?

Comment: just using logcat to test it out (model.getId() is just the index in the list)